Probability of a round-robin tournament having a distinct winner
This is a contest problem from Purple Comet $2022$. The question is:

Six gamers play a round-robin tournament where each gamer plays one game against each of the other five gamers. In each game there is one winner and one loser where each player is equally likely to win that game, and the result of each game is independent of the results of the other games. The probability that the tournament will end with exactly one gamer scoring more wins than any other player is $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m + n$.

I'll begin by saying I did find this question which has the correct answer. It is $\frac{20544}{32768}=\frac{321}{512}$, and $321+512=833$ which agrees with the answer key.
But I'm not totally satisfied with it. This is a contest question, and per the contest guidelines, calculators are allowed but each problem should be possible without a calculator. I'm looking for a solution that could reasonably have been used during the contest. Using something like Desmos is okay, but I'd really like a solution that doesn't involve writing code.
I'll say what I did and where I came to a dead end.
There will be $\binom{6}{2}=15$ matches that each have $2$ possible outcomes, for a total of $2^{15}=32768$ ways the tournament can unfold.
Call the players $A$ through $F$. My idea was to find the number of ways for $A$ to have more wins than anyone else. Then I can multiply by $6$ and work out the probability.
Case $1$: Player $A$ wins all $5$ matches they play. No other player can tie with $5$ wins, because they each lost to $A$. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ matches not involving $A$, and these matches can have any of $2^{10}=1024$ outcomes.
Case $2$ (the hard part): Player $A$ gets $4$ wins, and everyone else gets $3$ or fewer wins.
There have to be $15$ wins assigned to the players. Given $A$ has $4$ wins, that leaves $11$ others to be spread among $B$ through $F$, with none of them having more than $3$ wins. So, I need to partition $11$ into a sum of five values that are each $\leq3$.
I can do that in these ways: $\{3,3,3,2,0\}$, $\{3,3,3,1,1\}$, $\{3,2,2,2,2\}$, $\{3,3,2,2,1\}$.
And this is where I have become stuck. Take the $\{3,2,2,2,2\}$ partition, for example.
There are $\binom{5}{1}\times \binom{4}{4}=5$ ways to choose who has $3$ wins and who has $2$ wins.
Let's say that $B$ has $3$ wins. I'm not sure how to enumerate the possible tournaments where the wins counts are $(A,B,C,D,E,F)=(4,3,2,2,2,2)$. I know it is more than $1$!
Naturally, I have the same problem with the other partitions.
The partitioning method seems tedious, but maybe manageable?
I'm looking for help to finish that method, or for another method (not writing code!) altogether.

I believe converting this into a directed graph problem might make it easier to enumerate the possibilities. This is just what comes to mind at first glance.

I second the comment of @YuzurihaInori.  I spent about an hour trying to find elegant won-loss patterns to enumerate, and concluded that the approach is simply too primitive.  I then concluded that a brute force approach can not represent the intent of the problem composer(s), because then, the solution has no math educational value.  So, I strongly suspect that the problem composer(s) intend that something like graph theory (?  or group theory ?) be used.

I appreciate your effort. I sent an email to the contest writers, so fingers crossed they write back with some useful information.

Purple Comet rules say "All problems in the competition are designed so that they can be worked without the aid of calculating devices. On the other hand, participants are permitted to use calculators or computers, for example, to write a computer program in order solve or better understand a problem. ...
Participants may not use computers or any other communication devices to seek help with problem solutions from people or Internet resources outside of their own team members."

For case 2, PIE should work, where $G_A$ is the collection of games where player $A$ wins exactly 4 games, to find the number of games where exactly 1 person won 4 games. Then account for the game where someone also won 5 games.

Instead of focusing on a particular gamer scored more wins, we consider where any gamer scored more wins. (Granted we could have divided by 6, but you'd see why this is slightly more natural in case 2.)
Case 1, where exactly one gamer won 5 gams, thus has $ 6 \times 2^{10} = 6144$ games.
Case 2, where exactly one gamer won 4 games.
Let the gamers be labelled 1 to 6.
Let $G_i$ be the collection of games where gamer $i$ wins exactly 4 games.
Let's first consider where some player wins exactly 4 games.
Since the total number of games is 15, hence at most 3 players won exactly 4 games. PIE tells us that
$$| \cup G_i | = 6 | G_1 | - { 6 \choose 2 } |G_1 \cap G_2 | + { 6 \choose 3 } |G_1 \cap G_2 \cap G_3 |$$
We can calculate that

$|G_1| = {5 \choose 1 } \times 2^{10}$ - Choose who player 1 lost to, and there are 10 remaining matches to be determined
$|G_1 \cap G_2 | = {2 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times 2^6 $ - Choose whether player 1 or 2 won, winner of that match loses to someone, and there are 6 remaining matches to be determined
$|G_1 \cap G_2 \cap G_3| = 2 \times 2^3 $  - Choose whether $ 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3$ or $ 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2$, and there are 3 remaining matches to be determined.
Any larger intersection has size 0 as it involves 4 or more gamers.

Thus, $ |\cup G_i| = 23360. $
Now, we have to remove the following (disjoint) cases

Some gamer won 5 games, another gamer won 4 games: ${ 6 \choose 1} \times { 5 \choose 1 } \times 2^6$ = 1920 - Choose who won 5 games, choose who won 4 games, and there are 6 remaining matches to be determined.
At least 2 gamers won 4 games: Again we use PIE. Let $G_{i,j}$ be the collection of games where player i and j won exactly 4 games. From the calculations of $|G_1 \cap G_2|, |G_1 \cap G_2 \cap G_3| $ above, we conclude that

$|G_{i, j } | = {2 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times 2^6 $
$ |G_{i, j } \cap G_{k, l }| =0  $ if $|\{i, j, k, l \}| = 4$  and $2 \times 2^3$ otherwise.
$ |G_{i, j } \cap G_{k, l } \cap G_{m, n}| = 0 $if $| \{ i, j, k, l, m, n \} | \geq 4$ and $2 \times 2^3$ otherwise.
Any larger intersection has size 0 as it involves 4 or more people.
$$ |\cup G_{i, j}| = { 6 \choose 2 } \times {2 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times 2^6 - {6 \choose 3} \times 3 \times 2 \times 2^3 + {6 \choose 3 } \times 2 \times 2^3 = 7040$$


Verify that the 2 cases are indeed disjoint, as we cannot have 3 people who won 5, 4, 4 games.

So case 2 has $23360 - 1920 - 7040 = 14400$ cases.
In conclusion, the required probability is $\frac{ 6144 + 14400 }{ 2^{15} } = \frac{ 45120 } { 2^{15}} = \frac{321}{512}.$
Notes / Thoughts

This ended up being much more complicated than my initial comment implied (based on my interpretation), so I wrote it up.
The main idea is just Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. There's nothing really tricky involved, maybe just tedious/careful tracking.

Maybe the tricky part is in calculating "exactly 1 gamer did X = (at least 1 gamer did X) - (at least 2 gamers did X)".


It's not clear to me if this is the intended solution, or if theres a simpler solution.

Maybe we can calculate "exactly 1 gamer won 4 or more games = = (at least 1 gamer did X) - (at least 2 gamers did X)", and then add back "one gamer won 5 games, one gamer won 4 games". Though I took a stab at this, and it felt much more difficult.


My only use of calculators was basic arithmetic, so technically this could indeed be done without calculators or computers.
I would not want to calculate the case of 7 gamers using this approach, though it could still be done. Generalizing to $n$ isn't straightforward.


Thank you for the thorough answer! I emailed people at the contest and they shared a worked solution with me. It was nearly identical to yours, using PIE.
